# Frequency scaling on AppliedMicro's Mustang

Tags: 14.04, drivers, arm, cpufreq

I'm trying scale the frequency on AppliedMicro's Mustang board.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (aarch64) and I've installed the 'cpufrequtils' package but it seems that the kernel driver for the X-gene processor is missing.
Do you know where I can find the driver or can you propose an other way to scale the frequency?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I found the drivers from the kernel provided from AppliedMicro, compiled them as an external module, and loaded the module.
Everything works smoothly.